# UIImage view animation problem

Tags: iphone

I have done the effect of playing lots of images like below:

```
NSInteger faceNum = 12;

NSMutableArray *faceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:faceNum];

for (int i = 1;i<faceNum+1; i++) {
    NSString *facename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
      pathForResource:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"animationFace%d",i] ofType:@"png"];    
    UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:facename];    
    [faceArray addObject:faceImage];
}

 UIImageView *faceView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(414, 157, 161, 124)];

 faceView.animationImages = faceArray;    
 faceView.animationDuration = 30;    
 faceView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

 [faceView startAnimating];    
 [self.view addSubview:faceView];    
 [faceView release];    
 [faceArray release];
```

And how to add the EaseInEaseOut effect to this.One picture disappear gradually，then another picture appear gradually.
Thanks

Comment: your for loop looks weird as too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inbuilt fade-in and out feature with imageview startAnimating. You can achieve this by manually setting the alpha of two view laid over each other:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];

    imageviewToFadeOut.alpha = 0.0f;
    imageviewToFadeIn.alpha = 1.0f;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

and setImage manually alternatively to these UIViews.

```
[imageview setImage:image];
```

and to recursively call this method, use something like `[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withObject: afterDelay: ]` inside the method itself.

**Edit**: For clarity, specifying the recursion to call this method over and over with delay:

```
-(void)methodname {

.. (do your task)
[self performSelector:@selector(methodname) withObject:NULL afterDelay:10 ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,i've tried that,and it will work as expect,but how to achieve to repeat it always.

Comment: It seems can not use recursion to this method,the pic will show after this function is ended.I try while(yes) and recursion to this method,there is no change in my screen.

Comment: can you please explain where did it go wrong. You mention that pic will show after this function ended (why isn't it acceptable, the function will not take visible time to complete) and the performselector thing will make sure that the function is called again after "10" seconds or so